# PySpark: In certain situations, why am I not able to refer to columns as attributes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have the below code:

```
df = df \
    .withColumn('this_month_sales', df.units * df.rate) \
    .withColumn('this_year_sales_v1', df.this_month_sales + df.sales_till_last_month) \
    .withColumn('this_year_sales_v2', F.col('this_month_sales') + df.sales_till_last_month)
```

In this code,

- formula for `this_year_sales_v1` will cause a failure saying `this_month_sales` column doesn't exist or is not an attribute or something similar.
- formula for `this_year_sales_v2` will work

Why though? Aren't they doing the same thing essentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in the third line, the `this_month_sales` column does not exist in the original `df`. It was only created in the second line, but the attributes of the `df` variable has not been updated yet.

If you do something like

```
df = df \
    .withColumn('this_month_sales', df.units * df.rate)

df = df \
    .withColumn('this_year_sales_v1', df.this_month_sales + df.sales_till_last_month)
```

Then it should work because the `this_month_sales` column is now an attribute of `df` when the second line is run.

In general, I prefer using `F.col` to prevent this kind of problems.

Comment: I guessed that would be the problem. Is this related to lazy execution or so? When does a column actually get materialized?

Comment: It's not related to lazy execution. It's because the attributes of the `df` variable has not been updated to include the new column.