# Calculating quarterly growth

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some *daily* data in a `df`, which goes back as far as 1st January 2020. It looks similar to the below but with many `id1`s on each day.

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | id1 | id2  | cost  |
|------------|-----|------|-------|
| 2020-01-01 | 23  | 7253 | 5003  |
| 2020-01-01 | 23  | 7743 | 30340 |
| 2020-01-02 | 23  | 7253 | 450   |
| 2020-01-02 | 23  | 7743 | 4500  |
| ...        | ... | ...  | ...   |
| 2021-01-01 | 23  | 7253 | 5675  |
| 2021-01-01 | 23  | 134  | 1030  |
| 2021-01-01 | 23  | 3445 | 564   |
| 2021-01-01 | 23  | 4534 | 345   |
| ...        | ... | ...  | ...   |
```

I want like to calculate (1) the summed cost grouped by quarter and `id1`, (2) the growth % compared to the same quarter in the previous year.

I have grouped and calculated the summed cost like so:

```
grouped_quarterly = (
    df
    .withColumn('year_quarter', (F.year(sf.col('yyyy_mm_dd')) * 100 + F.quarter(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd'))
    .groupby('id1', 'year_quarter')
    .agg(
        F.sum('cost').alias('cost')
    )
)
```

But I am unsure how to get the growth compared to the previous year. Expected output based on the above sample:

```
| year_quarter | id1 | cost | cost_growth |
|--------------|-----|------|-------------|
| 202101       | 23  | 7614 | -81         |
```

It would also be nice to set `cost_growth` to 0 if the `id1` has no rows in the previous years quarter.

---

**Edit:** Below is an attempt to make the comparison but I get an error that there is no attribute `prev_value`:

```
grouped_quarterly = (
    df
    .withColumn('year_quarter', (F.year(sf.col('yyyy_mm_dd')) * 100 + F.quarter(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd'))
    .groupby('id1', 'year_quarter')
    .agg(
        F.sum('cost').alias('cost')
    )
)

w = Window.partitionBy('id1').orderBy('year_quarter')
growth = (
    grouped_quarterly
    .withColumn('prev_value', sf.lag(grouped_quarterly.cost).over(w))
    .withColumn('diff', sf.when(sf.isnull(grouped_quarterly.cost - grouped_quarterly.prev_value), 0).otherwise(grouped_quarterly.cost - grouped_quarterly.cost))
)
```

---

**Edit #2**: The window function seems to take the previous quarter, regardless of year. This means my `prev_value` column is the previous quarter rather than the same quarter from the previous year:

```
grouped_quarterly.where(sf.col('id1') == 222).sort('year_quarter').show(10,False)

| id1 | year_quarter | cost |
|-----|--------------|------|
| 222 | 202001       | 73   |
| 222 | 202002       | 246  |
| 222 | 202003       | 525  |
| 222 | 202004       | -27  |
| 222 | 202101       | 380  |

w = Window.partitionBy('id1').orderBy('year_quarter')
growth = (
    grouped_quarterly
    .withColumn('prev_value', sf.lag(sf.col('cost')).over(w))
    .withColumn('diff', sf.when(sf.isnull(sf.col('cost') - sf.col('prev_value')), 0).otherwise(sf.col('cost') - sf.col('prev_value')))
)

growth.where(sf.col('id1') == 222).sort('year_quarter').show(10,False)

| id1 | year_quarter | cost | prev_value | diff |
|-----|--------------|------|------------|------|
| 222 | 202001       | 73   | null       | 0    |
| 222 | 202002       | 246  | 73         | 173  |
| 222 | 202003       | 525  | 246        | 279  |
| 222 | 202004       | -27  | 525        | -522 |
| 222 | 202101       | 380  | -27        | 407  |
```

---

**Edit #3**: Using the quarter in the partitioning results in a null `prev_value` for all rows:

```
grouped_quarterly.where(sf.col('id1') == 222).sort('year_quarter').show(10,False)

| id1 | year_quarter | cost |
|-----|--------------|------|
| 222 | 202001       | 73   |
| 222 | 202002       | 246  |
| 222 | 202003       | 525  |
| 222 | 202004       | -27  |
| 222 | 202101       | 380  |


w = Window.partitionBy(sf.col('id1'), sf.expr('substring(string(year_quarter), 2)')).orderBy('year_quarter')
growth = (
    grouped_quarterly
    .withColumn('prev_value', sf.lag(sf.col('cost')).over(w))
    .withColumn('diff', sf.when(sf.isnull(sf.col('cost') - sf.col('prev_value')), 0).otherwise(sf.col('cost') - sf.col('prev_value')))
)

growth.where(sf.col('id1') == 222).sort('year_quarter').show(10,False)

| id1 | year_quarter | cost | prev_value | diff  |
|-----|--------------|------|------------|-------|
| 222 | 202001       | 73   | null       | 0     |
| 222 | 202002       | 246  | null       | 0     |
| 222 | 202003       | 525  | null       | 0     |
| 222 | 202004       | -27  | null       | 0     |
| 222 | 202101       | 380  | null       | 0     |
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470314/pyspark-column-transformation-calculate-percentage-change-for-each-group-in-a-c)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to adjust the solution but run into syntax errors. I edited my original Q to include my attempt using the Window function

Comment: Then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66476769/14165730)

Comment: use `sf.col` to specify column names

Comment: That fixed the issue! However the output isn't as expected, I've added a second edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the quarter in the partitioning as well, so that `lag` will give you the value in the same quarter last year:

```
w = Window.partitionBy(sf.col('id1'), sf.expr('substring(string(year_quarter), -2)')).orderBy('year_quarter')
```

Comment: Cannot use `yyyy_mm_dd` there since the `grouped_quarterly` df is already grouped to `year_quarter` so the field is no longer usable

Comment: oops, then you can get the quarter from the `year_quarter` variable. see edited answer?

Comment: I get an error that the `right` function is undefined but adding this also errors - `from pyspark.sql.functions import right` -  'cannot import name 'right''

Comment: maybe your spark version is too old... try substring in the edited answer?

Comment: That worked but now `prev_value` is null in the output. I added a third edit to show it

Comment: should be `-2`, not `2`, inside substring